# Define inverted chord with roman numerals with JFugue

Tags: java, jfugue

[This pdf](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/novak/cs314/jfugue-chapter2.pdf) says that inverted chords can be defined by adding `^` to the end of a chord definition, but this only works with explicit chord definitions as far as I can tell.

For example:

```
ChordProgression cp = new ChordProgression("I^");
cp.setKey("C");
System.out.println(cp.getChords()[0].getBassNote());
Chord c = new Chord("Cmaj^");
System.out.println(c.getBassNote());
```

Outputs:

```
C
E
```

Even though both should be `E`

Comment: I think I didn't consider inversions in the ChordProgression string. I'll look into adding this.

BTW, you're looking at a PDF for an older version of JFugue. It's no longer accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to your suggestion, this is now possible using [JFugue 5.0.9](http://www.jfugue.org/).

```
// This will result in "C4MAJ D4MAJ^ E4MAJ^^ F4MAJ^^^ G4MIN^^^ A4MIN^^ B4MIN^"
// (using C4 as the default root note for each of the chords, unless otherwise
// specified by setRoot("note"). 
ChordProgression cp = new ChordProgression("I II^ III^^ IV^^^ v^^^ vi^^ vii^");
```